# On the use of "der" in this context

Tags: sentence-structure

[This book](https://www.amazon.de/Aristoteles-Die-Hauptwerke-Ein-Lesebuch/dp/3772083145/ref=pd_sim_14_4?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=DQP73GK9ZN36P38H7CWC) begins with these lines:

> Aristoteles ist einer der bedeutendsten europäischen Denker und einer
>   der großen Kirchenvater des menschlichen Geistes. **Der** *sowohl für
>   die Philosophie als auch für die Einzelwissenschaften* **überragende
>   Forscher und Lehrer** prägt keineswegs nur das Abendland.

As far as I can tell, *der* here is the definite article of *Forscher* and *Lehrer*, both masculine nouns.

If I am correct in assuming this much about *der*, why is it then separated from its noun(s) by *sowohl für die Philosophie als auch für die Einzelwissenschaften*; and why isn't the whole sentence written like this:

**Der überragende Forscher und Lehrer, sowohl für die Philosophie als auch für die Einzelwissenschaften, prägt keineswegs nur das Abendland.**

Does separating the noun from its definite article sound better in German or the reasons for doing so are other than purely euphonic?

Comment: The original sentence is already a bit weird - "für die Philosophie überragend" doesn't make a lot of sense to me. "Für die Philosophie [bedeutend|überragend wichtig|prägend]" would make a lot more sense. The preposition "für" and "überragen" don't fit at all.

Comment: The *Der* refers to the *Aristoteles* of the previous sentence. The difference between your version and the one of the book are small and in this very sentence only in emphasis. I like the books version more, while it sounds abit more complicated. I think your version should be the more common one, at least in spoken german.

Comment: @ikadfoanhfda Then, if _der_ refers to Aristotle, it is a relative pronoun, not a definite article. Logically at least, that would be even stranger than my own version, with _der_ as a definite article.

Comment: @ikadfoanhfda No. The **article** refers to *Forscher*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purpose of explaining the sentence structure, let us simplify the original sentence and remove the irrelevant words in parenthesis:

> Der (sowohl) für die Philosophie (als auch für die Einzelwissenschaften) überragende Forscher (und Lehrer) prägt keineswegs nur das Abendland.

So, we have

> Der für die Philosophie überragende Forscher prägt keineswegs nur das Abendland.

As you have altready noticed, ***der* is the definite article of *Forscher*** and ***überragend*, meaning *formidable*, is an adjective**. So, we have the basic structure "*Der überragende Forscher ...*".

However, the author wants to specify for whom Aristotele is formidable. In German, you can **add the specification attributively** and say *für die Philosophie überragend*. In summary, we have "*Der für die Philosophie überragende Forscher ...*". That's it.

---

Your suggestion, which after simplification reads

> Der überragende Forscher, für die Philosophie, prägt keineswegs nur das Abendland.

is not correct, neither contentwise nor grammatically. Regarding the content, the attribute *für die Philosophie* specifies *Forscher* instead of *überragend*. Regarding grammar, a verb is missing in the relative clause. To keep the definite article close to the noun, you could say something like

> Der Forscher, der für die Philosophie überragend ist, prägt keineswegs nur das Abendland.

Here, *der für die Philosophie überragend ist* is a proper [relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause). Or you can use the [apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) *für die Philosophie überragend* and say something like

> Der Forscher, für die Philosophie überragend, prägt keineswegs nur das Abendland.